# How do I parse an HTML file in React Native?

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, html-parsing

How can I get an HTML file from file system and parse specific elements from it.

For example, given the html snippet below, how can I extract the table content and render it?

```html
<html>
<div>
  <h1>header</h1>
  <table id="a" border="1">
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>content A</th>
    <th>contetn A</th>
    <th>content A</th>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>content B</th>
    <th>content B</th>
    <th>content B</th>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<footer>footer</footer>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using this library: [react-native-htmlviewer](https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview). It takes html and renders it as native views. You can also customize the way elements get rendered.

```
// only render the <table> nodes in your html
function renderNode(node, index, siblings, parent, defaultRenderer) {
  if (node.name !== 'table'){
    return (
      <View key={index}>
        {defaultRenderer(node.children, parent)}
      </View>
    )l
  }

}

// your html
const htmlContent = `<html></html>`;

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HTMLView value={htmlContent} renderNode={renderNode} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just download HTML with fetch(), parse it using [fast-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-html-parser), write result to state and render that state with [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html)

Comment: @Stich You able to find example on "fast-html-browser" Github project page.

Comment: what react native version do you use? I have tried from 43 to 44 but have the same issue with module "fast-html-parser": UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `util` from `/.../node_modules/apollojs/server.js`

What versions in your package.json in these lines?:
"react": "^16.0.0-alpha.6",
"react-native": "^0.43.4"

Comment: And sorry but I cannot find "fast-html-browser" project on Github. Could you provide a link?

Comment: doesn't work for react native 0.41.2, same problem as @Stich

Comment: New issue was opened in github project:
https://github.com/ashi009/node-fast-html-parser/issues/11

Comment: Hi here is the answer for this

You can fix this if you explicitly install util with npm install util.

https://github.com/ashi009/node-fast-html-parser/issues/11

Comment: it works well but you need to run "npm install util" to resolve module util

Answer (score 5):

Get html with fetch() and parse with [react-native-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-html-parser), process and display with WebView.

```
import DOMParser from 'react-native-html-parser';

fetch('http://www.google.com').then((response) => {
   const html = response.text();    
   const parser = new DOMParser.DOMParser();
   const parsed = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
   parsed.getElementsByAttribute('class', 'b');
});
```

P.S. fast-html-parser from other answers didn't work for me. I got multiple errors while installing it with react-native 0.54.

Comment: Project is no longer valid on GitHub

Comment: My ide wants `@types/react-native-html-parser` for TypeScript which seem to be non existant

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this package [react-native-render-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html), is so famous and very simple for using

Comment: How do use this to parse html string? to i can use getQueryparams and so on?