# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: DOMParser

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: DOMParser

I am parsing fetched html string into dom object for cross-platform React Native app.

I am using the pure native DOMParser(ex. new DOMParser()), not any external dom parser library.

I do not get this reference error when I run expo in web browser mode. However, when I scan the qr code to view it on my android galaxy phone, I get the above error message.

I have tried manually storing native code for DOMParser from global into a variable to fore reference pointing. This attempt gives me another error:
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor. This makes me think that expo or android does not have DOMParser in its global. Such situtation led me to current process of finding a support that fills in the gap and reading into expo's documentation for any clues.

I cannot seem to find the same error that I am experiencing even after long hours of googling.

Please help with your knowledge and experience thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an HTML file in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343951/how-do-i-parse-an-html-file-in-react-native)